# preg_match out puts arrays and no content

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to parse the info inside of a specific div tag and for some reason it keeps outputting arrays and no info and I cant figure it out for the life of me.

This is what I have.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=^DJI&a=05&b=4&c=2012&d=06&e=6&f=2012&g=d');
$i=0;
$classes = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black', 'purple', 'grey');
$ci = 0;
foreach ($html->find('.yfnc_datamodoutline1 .yfnc_tabledata1') as $element){

$symbols = $element->outertext;
$hp = '<div class="'.$classes[$ci].'">'.$symbols.'</div>';
$ci++;
if($ci == count($classes)) $ci = 0;
preg_match_all("'<div class=\"black\">([^<]*)</div>'si", $hp, $match);

print_r($hp);
//print_r($match);
```

}

Now if I print out $hp there is clearly information with the div tags im trying to get the info from, the output looks like this.

```
<div class="red">Jul 6, 2012</div>
<div class="blue">12,889.40</div>
<div class="yellow">12,889.40</div>
<div class="green">12,702.99</div>
<div class="black">12,772.47</div>
<div class="purple">967,600</div>
<div class="grey">12,772.47</div>
<div class="red">Jul 5, 2012</div>
<div class="blue">12,941.85</div>
<div class="yellow">12,961.30</div>
<div class="green">12,852.24</div>
<div class="black">12,896.67</div>
<div class="purple">978,000</div>
<div class="grey">12,896.67</div>
```

black is the div im trying to get,
but i keep getting arrays that look like this when I try to print $match in the preg_match function

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, You can also run the code [here and test it out](http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=j0msOAc8bUiViWT_o-oj8g) just open the index file.

Comment: Right click -> view source. And now?

Comment: Well, basic instructions: at the page where you `print_r($match);`.. Right click with your mouse or other favorite pointing device, choose 'view source','source', or whatever seems closest in your browser of choice, and re-examine the output there.

Comment: I dont understand what I am suppose to be looking for, but the output looks like this Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <div class="black">Array</div>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
        )

) pretty much the same as above

Comment: Id does not look anything like the stuff above, that's the point. All kinds of `div` matches. However, I suspect that rather then regexing [something like this](http://pastebin.com/FMzdXjWP) is more desirable.

Comment: Actually that works better then my code, only one question. Do you know why it doesnt get the 1st 3 rows?

Comment: Hm, what 1st 3 rows doesn't it get? Because it starts here with `12,772.47`, as the first row is at this point, and ends with `12,101.46`, as is the last row? I'm not which content you mean...?

Comment: if you go [here](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=^DJI+Historical+Prices) and look under the close table, it has 12,617.43, 12,653.12, 12,736.29 as the 1st 3 rows of data but starts at the 4th row which is 12,772.47, I really appreciate you answering me and helping me I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, that is because the one url ([historical prizes until now](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EDJI+Historical+Prices) is not the other url ([historical prices until July 6th](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=^DJI&a=05&b=4&c=2012&d=06&e=6&f=2012&g=d) ) .... Seems logical to me...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the / before si and you need to remove the single quotes as they are taken as part of the expression.

```
preg_match_all("<div class=\"black\">([^<]*)</div>/si", $hp, $match);
```

**EDITED: Try this out.**

Also you might find this site useful: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

```
  $html = '<div class="red">Jul 6, 2012</div>
<div class="blue">12,889.40</div>
<div class="yellow">12,889.40</div>
<div class="green">12,702.99</div>
<div class="black">12,772.47</div>
<div class="purple">967,600</div>
<div class="grey">12,772.47</div>
<div class="red">Jul 5, 2012</div>
<div class="blue">12,941.85</div>
<div class="yellow">12,961.30</div>
<div class="green">12,852.24</div>
<div class="black">12,896.67</div>
<div class="purple">978,000</div>
<div class="grey">12,896.67</div>';

  preg_match_all("/<div class=\"black\">([^<]*)<\/div>/i", $html, $matches);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($matches[1]);

?>
```

Comment: yeah that doesnt fix it... Just more arrays =)

Comment: `'` is just used as delimiter instead of `/`. Unorthodox yes, but not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i'll write it:

```
preg_match_all("/<div class=\"black\">(.*)<\/div>/si", $hp, $match);
```

Comment: this still is giving me a bunch of arrays, but its returning the content with the div as well instead of just the numbers inside of the div

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I don't think you need to use regex here at all.  In the data you are looping over you already know if you have class `black`.

In your loop couldn't you do

```
if ($classes[$ci] === 'black') {
    echo $symbols;
}
```

You could easily store that in an array as well.